# How do I remain on a specific line after a ReadLine?

Tags: c#, console

I'm building a webshop mockup in a console app (school project) where the user registers with a number of readlines. For example; the user is prompted to input their desired age, but if the age is lower than 15 or higher than 100 or if the input isn't parseable as an int, the user gets a .Write("Error, try again: ").

My goal is to remain on the same line until the user inputs an age that is valid.

`Error, try again: _______`

right now it just keeps posting the same error message making the whole thing unreadable.

```
public static void ClearLine()
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - (Console.WindowWidth >= Console.BufferWidth ? 1 : 0));
}
```

With this code I am able to remain on the same line, but the error message disappears & the text i just wrote still remains and the console simply writes over it, it's better for sure but I'd love it if I could just clear the text and keep inputting until it's valid

```
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) ||
     number > maxValue || number < minValue)
{
    Console.Write("Wrong input, try again: ");
    Thread.Sleep(800);
    ClearLine();
}
```

and this is the code that tries the input

Comment: There is no user input in your code?

Comment: The code linked is simply the method that tries to determine where the userinput is located in the console

Comment: edited it in in case you're curious

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're writing a Console app, not a Web app (webshop)

Your teacher must be over 60 to put this requirement. In the old days, we did it like this on a VT-330 terminal. Input only backspace, ENTER and numbers..

```
 string squestion = "What's your age ?";
 int lenquestion = squestion.Length + 1;
 while (true) {
   string sanswer = "";
   Console.Write(squestion + " ___");
   Console.SetCursorPosition(lenquestion, Console.CursorTop);
   while (true) {
     var c = Console.ReadKey();
     if (c.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) break;
     if (c.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace) sanswer += c.KeyChar;
       else if (sanswer != "") sanswer = sanswer.Remove(sanswer.Length - 1);
     Console.SetCursorPosition(lenquestion, Console.CursorTop);
     Console.Write(sanswer + '_');
     Console.SetCursorPosition(lenquestion+sanswer.Length,  Console.CursorTop);
   }
   Console.Write(squestion+" "+sanswer);
   if (int.TryParse(sanswer, out int age)) {
     if (age < 60  || age > 120) {
       Console.WriteLine("\t  ... you lied ! try again.."); // same line
       continue;
      }
    }
   else {
     Console.WriteLine("\t  ... invalid input ! try again.."); // same line
     continue;
    }
   Console.WriteLine("\t  ... thank you for being honest !");
   Console.WriteLine("\nPress <enter> to leave..");
   Console.ReadLine();
   break;
 }
```

Comment: Ah I suppose you're right, it's a webshop mockup in a console environment that you navigate much like your example but with numbers for each menu item and readlines to input certain data. It is connected to a local database from which it acquires data